# User Defined Metric in Caret Package

Tags: r

I am looking to utilise the caret package with a metric that is not one of the default options. For the example below I use the Metrics package. I have read all of the relevant questions on StackOverflow as well as the guide on the caret website but still am receiving errors.

In the example below I wish to use Mean Absolute Error.

create a function:

```
maefunction<-function(data, lev=NULL, model=NULL){
  require(Metrics)
  MAE<-mae(data[, "obs"], data[, "pred"])
  out<-c(MAE)
  out
}
```

Now I insert the function into the trainControl

```
library(caret)
GBM<-train(train$result~., data=train, method="gbm", trControl=trainControl(summaryFunction=maefunction), metric=MAE)
```

I receive the following message

```
Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor) : 
Results must be all atomic, or all data frames
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (metric %in% c("Accuracy", "Kappa")) stop(paste("Metric",  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (metric == "ROC" & !ctrl$classProbs) stop("train()'s use of ROC codes requires                class probabilities. See the classProbs option of trainControl()") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (!(metric %in% perfNames)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  The metric "4" was not in the result set.  will be used instead.The metric "0.5" was    not in the result set.  will be used instead.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that you have to use a named vector (see the example below). I didn't explicitly say that in the documentation so I will update that section.

Max

```
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)

maeSummary <- function (data,
                        lev = NULL,
                        model = NULL) {
   out <- mae(data$obs, data$pred)  
   names(out) <- "MAE"
   out
}

mControl <- trainControl(summaryFunction = maeSummary)
marsGrid <- expand.grid(degree = 1, nprune = (1:10) * 2)

set.seed(1)
earthFit <- train(medv ~ .,
                  data = BostonHousing, 
                  "earth",
                  tuneGrid = marsGrid,
                  metric = "MAE",
                  maximize = FALSE,
                  trControl = mControl)
```

Comment: When I run this code, I get the following message "Error in ctrl$summaryFunction(testOutput, lev, method) :" has something changed since the answer was given?

Comment: I got the first part of the error saying mae was not found. That's because in the code there is no call to the Metrics package you used originally. Just including library(Metrics) worked for me. Anyway, this will allow you to choose the metaparameters of the model (nprune) with the lowest MAE, but you might be interested in make the algorithm for the earth model to directly minimize MAE for every metaparameter combination.

Answer (score 0):

```
mae <- function(pred, obs) 
{
  isNA <- is.na(pred)
  pred <- pred[!isNA]
  obs <- obs[!isNA]
  if (!is.factor(obs) & is.numeric(obs)) {
    if (length(obs) + length(pred) == 0) {
      out <- rep(NA, 2)
    }
    else {
      if (length(unique(pred)) < 2 || length(unique(obs)) < 
          2) {
        resamplCor <- NA
      }
      else {
        resamplCor <- try(cor(pred, obs, use = "pairwise.complete.obs"), 
                          silent = TRUE)
        if (class(resamplCor) == "try-error") 
          resamplCor <- NA
      }
      mse <- mean((pred - obs)^2)
      mae <- mean(abs(pred - obs))
      n <- length(obs)
      out <- c(mae, sqrt(mse), resamplCor^2)
    }
    names(out) <- c("MAE", "RMSE", "Rsquared")
  }
  else {
    if (length(obs) + length(pred) == 0) {
      out <- rep(NA, 2)
    }
    else {
      pred <- factor(pred, levels = levels(obs))
      requireNamespaceQuietStop("e1071")
      out <- unlist(e1071::classAgreement(table(obs, pred)))[c("diag", 
                                                               "kappa")]
    }
    names(out) <- c("Accuracy", "Kappa")
  }
  if (any(is.nan(out))) 
    out[is.nan(out)] <- NA
  out
}



MAEFunction <- function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) 
{
  if (is.character(data$obs)) 
    data$obs <- factor(data$obs, levels = lev)
  mae(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"])
}
```